# Radio Button change layout activity Android Studio

Tags: java, android

[image: main menu]
[main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lhA8s.png)

[image: difficulty image]
[difficulty image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fILis.png)

Hello I'm developing a game. But I can't fix my game difficulty. How do I make the hardmode button run? I want when I checked the RadioButton any of them my play button in main menu will change the layout activity. help

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int selectedid = mMode.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(selectedid == R.id.radiohard){
            Intent intentMain = new Intent(Settings.this, HardMode.class);
            startActivity(intentMain);
            Log.i("Content ", " Main layout ");
        }
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: up guys need help

Comment: `I want when I checked the RadioButton any of them my play button in main menu will change the layout activity.` Do you want to reset the layout or does the selected radion button is not correct? Please add the details to your question.

Comment: like a game when they have a difficulties, when i change the difficulty my play button will change the layout, because i have different layout  activity for difficulties, i have easy layout activity, normal layout activity, and hard layout activity. my question is how do i change my difficulty using radiobutton?

Comment: You can set visibility of previous layout to INVISIBLE and visibility of new layout to VISIBLE. @Gelok

Comment: okay sir, can u give me example code?

Comment: Like userlevel that intent different

Comment: How do you call the `Settings.class` from your `MainMenu.class`? is it via `Intent`?

Comment: I want when i change the difficulty my mainmenu play button will change the intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        if (db.difficultyeasy() == 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } 
        else if(db.difficultyhard() == 3){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HardMode.class);
            startActivity(intent);
       }
});
```